# Do you have to have exactly 60 cards in a Magic the Gathering deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Do you have to have exactly 60 cards in a Magic the Gathering deck? Some people I've talked to at FNM say yes, others say no.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that, in most Constructed decks, it's overwhelmingly better if you *can* keep your deck size as close to 60 cards as possible.  The larger the deck the greater the unpredictability of your draws, and from most angles that's a significant disadvantage.

Comment: To add to @thesunneversets 's comment, you're also limited to a maximum of 4 of any specific card (besides basic land) so a larger deck will also contain a wider variety of cards that may or may not work well together.  The best smaller decks tend to be focused around a fairly specific play style - cards that will symbiotize.  This is *much* more difficult with a large deck.

Comment: Related: [Why would you want to play with a deck bigger than 60 cards in MTG?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/179/5573)

Comment: Confusion could be compounded by the fact many (all that I've played I believe) MtG computer games require your decks to be size 60.

Answer (score 26):

No, not at all. You probably should keep it near the minimum since a deck of minimum size will provide more consistent results than a larger deck, but you are not obligated to do so.

- For *constructed* events, your deck must have *at least* 60 cards<sup>[CR 100.2a]</sup> (plus an optional sideboard of *no more than* 15 cards<sup>[CR 100.4a]</sup>).
- For *limited* (draft and sealed) events, your deck must have *at least* 40 cards<sup>[CR 100.2b]</sup>.

Additionally all decks no matter the format must be "able to be shuffled within a reasonable time"

There are many [formats](http://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/gameplay/rules-and-formats/formats) that impose additional limitations. Notably,

- For *Commander* games, your deck must have *exactly* 100 cards (including your Commander)<sup>[CR 903.5a]</sup>.

I could quote you the rules, but [Battle of Wits](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Battle%20of%20Wits) is much more convincing :)

---

Note: When this answer was originally written the side board was limited to *exactly* 15 cards. This has changed. I have updated this information to match current rules since it doesn't affect the answer.

Comment: In a _Conspiracy_ Limited tournament, Advantageous Proclamation could also reduce your deck size below 40. The card is only legal in Conspiracy Limited, though.

Comment: There is also a 30-card minimum for 4-booster sealed, and Mini-Masters(pack wars).

Comment: I'm going to limit my answer to the rules. Advantageous Proclamation is a case of a card overriding the rules (as allowed by the first Golden Rule). As for the formats @esoterik mention, they do not appear in [the official list](http://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/gameplay/rules-and-formats/formats), and it would still be illegal to create decks with fewer than 40 cards even if the format allows decks as small as 30.

Comment: @ikegami if the format allows it, how is it illegal?

Comment: @esoterik, Having a deck with 30 cards when CR 100.2b requires the deck to have a minimum of 40 cards is illegal because 30 is less than 40. I don't know what else you want me to say.

Answer (score 6):

You certainly don't, not in any normal MtG format.  60 card decks are the *minimum* in most Constructed formats, but there is no upper bound.  Commander decks are all the same size... but they are 100 cards big, not 60.  In typical Limited environments (Draft/Sealed) the minimum size is 40, with an upper limit determined only by the size of your cardpool (and even then you can add a LOT of basic lands on top).

If you want to prove to someone that a Magic deck doesn't have to have exactly 60 cards in it, the quickest way is probably to refer them to [Battle of Wits](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=288878) - a famous card that doesn't even make sense in a world of uniform 60-card decks.

Comment: Battle of wits does prove otherwise, I agree. But usually it is played in decks that are practically composed of nothing but counters and cards that help you find it. It works, but it is not that strong a strategy. When it comes to instant wins, I would much rather play with mazes end.

Answer (score 1):

By default, sixty is just the minimum in constructed, and the minimum is forty in limited:

> 100.2a In constructed play (a way of playing in which each player creates his or her own deck ahead of time), each deck must contain at least sixty cards. […]
>
> 100.2b In limited play (a way of playing in which each player gets the same quantity of unopened Magic product such as booster packs and creates his or her own deck using only this product and basic land cards), each deck must contain at least forty cards. […]
>
> 100.5. There is no maximum deck size.

The only official variant that changes this is Commander, which requires exactly one hundred cards:

> 903.5a Each deck must contain exactly 100 cards, including its commander.

Answer (score -5):

For the record, I have not played in a few years. If you are playing with friends than anything can go, if they are ok for it.

Tournament rules are still as follows, "Players may have a sideboard of up to a maximum of 15 cards, and exchanges of cards between games are not required to be on a one-for-one basis, so long as the player adheres to the 60 card minimum deck size"

There was a rule were you could only have 4 cards with the same name unless the card had special rules limiting it, at the time you could only have one "Wrath of God" or any non-named land for example. Having said that most people would run around 15 land and around 45 other cards... in this case do 16 land and 44 other cards leaving you only 11 different cards give or take. You would do this to increase your odds of getting your strategic cards. When drawing randomly, it's not luck it is a number game, play the odds!

Having said that, I once had a massive 120 card deck. It played awful due to the odds being against me with every draw.

Comment: Not to be rude, but this doesn't add anything that wasn't already in the existing answers, and the information in the third paragraph is confusing/wrong.

Comment: Now, about that third paragraph - the term for only being able to play one copy is "restricted". Wrath of God has never been on the restricted list, and I know for sure that "any non-named land" is not restricted. Also, 15 lands in a 60 card deck is suicide in basically every deck except for a handful of eternal format decks. The fastest, leanest deck in recent standard history played 18, and the entire deck is 1 and 2 drops. If you just delete that paragraph entirely, I think it would improve your answer.

Answer (score -9):

It is good to have a large deck because if someone had a decking deck you would lose instantly! It is also good to have a deck of 60 cards because you have a better chance to get your good card! This is my opinion!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please note that this space is for answers to the question only, not for discussions and opinions. As such, a mod will likely delete this, but I hope you stick around to ask and answer questions!

Comment: I disagree that this does not answer the question. I don't believe it's a _good_ answer, but it is _an_ answer. Q: Do you have to have exactly 60 cards? A: It's good to have a large deck, and it's good to have a small deck. The implication is that no, exactly 60 is not required.