# Why did Yu-Gi-Oh! change from an unlimited deck size to a 60 card maximum deck size?

Tags: yu-gi-oh, history

When *Yu-Gi-Oh!* first started, an unlimited deck size was allowed. Now there is a limit of 60 cards. It may not always be advantageous to play more cards (see [Why would one want more than 40 cards in their deck?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/40532/3389)), but why was this restriction added? After all, *Magic the Gathering* has cards like [Battle of Wits](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBattle%20of%20Wits%5d) that rely on decks of over 200 and they seem to be doing fine.

Comment: The 60 card limit has quite some time, almost from the beginning if I recall (urgh, can't find a Rulebook v1.0 to check out)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[If Reddit is to be believed](https://www.reddit.com/r/yugioh/comments/4q6wbm/what_happened_to_the_deck_size_limit/), there was a person at a German regional tournament who thoroughly abused this by bringing a deck with 2222 cards (enough for about 740 cards with 3 duplicates each). To make matters worse, as many cards as possible were added so that the deck had to be shuffled during the game as often as possible. While it was definitely poor sportsmanship, is was unquestionably legal, so Konami instituted the maximum deck size shortly thereafter.

> It was originally 40+. There was no limit. I'm pretty sure the 60 card limit was introduced because some guy brought a deck that was outrageously large to a tourney.

> I think at one event long ago in Germany some dude brought a 2k card deck or something? I guess Konami decided to set an actual limit then.

This story has appeared in other places across the web, with [this forum post](https://www.pojo.biz/board/showthread.php?s=cefda0e4c3a2bb8f267a455d0bcb9014&p=27374117#post27374117) including a picture of the deck purportedly being carried in (and a several dozen page deck list).

[image: Yu-Gi-Oh! unlimited size deck 2222 card deck]

[image: Yu-Gi-Oh! unlimited size deck 2222 card list]

Comment: Seems that the story appears other places as well (like [gamefaqs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/161239-yu-gi-oh-legacy-of-the-duelist/75142418)). Also, this took place during the [YuGiOh 5D's](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_5D%27s) series, according to YuGiOh [wikia](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Maximum_Deck_size)

Comment: Flipping 'ell, that is ridiculous! How long did that duel take?

Comment: @VortexYT Since it was a tournament, presumably until time ran out or until the other side surrendered out of frustration.

Comment: yeah, i would imagine many people got annoyed just at the amount of time it takes to finish turns where you kick off stuff that requires you constantly shuffle.